# part of the code is being ignored - why?

Tags: python

The script is reading the temperature from an DS18B20 sensor, which it prints to the terminal. 
Python is ignoring the code part where it should send this data to thingspeak.com
It gives no error codes.

Anyone got a clue what's wrong?

My code:

```
# Temperature to Thingspeak.com
# python
import httplib, urllib, os, glob, time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def getpid():
    dataAsString = str(os.getpid())

    fb = open("/home/pi/pidfile.pid","w")
    fb.write(dataAsString)
    fb.close()

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c

        temperature = read_temp()
        params = urllib.urlencode({'field1': temperature, 'key':'Pon_aquí_tu_key'})
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
        conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        print response.status, response.reason
        data = response.read()
        conn.close()
        tme.sleep(16)

while true:
        getpid()
        dataAsInt = str(read_temp())
        dataAsString = str(dataAsInt)
        print dataAsString
        time.sleep(16)
```

**EDIT**
Running this code alone send temperature to thingspeak once, and then stop.

```
# Registrador de temperatura Nergiza.com
# python
import httplib, urllib, os, glob, time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c

temperatura = read_temp()
params = urllib.urlencode({'field1': temperatura, 'key':'Pon_aquí_tu_key'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":
        "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

Comment: what is the response code?

Comment: There are no response code, it prints the temperature to the terminal. But it do not send the the temperature to thingspeak.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a `return` statement the code following it would not be executed. Perhaps you should have dedented the code after the return like this:

```
# Temperature to Thingspeak.com
# python
import httplib, urllib, os, glob, time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def getpid():
    dataAsString = str(os.getpid())

    fb = open("/home/pi/pidfile.pid","w")
    fb.write(dataAsString)
    fb.close()

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c

    temperature = read_temp()
    params = urllib.urlencode({'field1': temperature, 'key':'Pon_aquí_tu_key'})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
    conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status, response.reason
    data = response.read()
    conn.close()
    tme.sleep(16)

while true:
        getpid()
        dataAsInt = str(read_temp())
        dataAsString = str(dataAsInt)
        print dataAsString
        time.sleep(16)
```

But then `read_temp_raw` would not return anything if `equal_pos == -1` (it doesn't do that anyway).

Comment: I've tryed to move the code part from temperature = read_temp() all way to the left, and moving it under the while true: part. This doesn't change anything.

Comment: You would of course decide when that code should be run. In that position it might not be what you'd want. Moving it to after the `while True` loop won't work as that loop should never terminate and the code after it wouldn't run.